# Helm and LaTeX mode

Tags: helm, latex

When I run the command `LaTeX-environment` (bound to `C-c C-e` by default) Helm properly selects from a list of all relevant environments (i.e. the same list I'd get without Helm turned on). The prompt reads "Environment type: (default foo)" where 'foo' is the value stored in `LaTeX-default-environment` (which is in turn set to whatever I ended up using in the last call to `LaTeX-environment`). If I hit return now, however, I get an 'abstract' environment, the first entry in the Helm buffer.

How can I get Helm to respect `LaTeX-default-environment`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You cannot](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/207). According to `helm`'s author it is AUCTEX' fault for not using `completing-read` correctly which makes `helm-mode` return the candidate verbatim. A possible workaround is described in the linked thread which is either making AUCTEX' authors fix the bug for every instance of `completing-read` or patching it yourself.

To do the latter, the following should work (untested, most code taken from AUCTEX):

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(defun LaTeX-environment (arg)
      (interactive "*P")
      (let ((environment (completing-read (concat "Environment type: (default "
                                                  (if (TeX-near-bobp)
                                                      "document"
                                                    LaTeX-default-environment)
                                                  ") ")
                                          (LaTeX-environment-list) nil t nil
                                          'LaTeX-environment-history LaTeX-default-environment)))
        ;; Get default
        (cond ((and (zerop (length environment))
                    (TeX-near-bobp))
               (setq environment "document"))
              ((zerop (length environment))
               (setq environment LaTeX-default-environment))
              (t
               (setq LaTeX-default-environment environment)))

        (let ((entry (assoc environment (LaTeX-environment-list))))
          (if (null entry)
              (LaTeX-add-environments (list environment)))

          (if arg
              (LaTeX-modify-environment environment)
            (LaTeX-environment-menu environment))))))
```

Comment: [Already fixed upstream](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/latex.el?id=5f31fced0fe7f83797860a08e69be711ae7f6799).

Comment: Thanks, guess the questioner has to update his AUCTEX installation then and check whether this fixes it. If not, the snippet above should still apply.